# How to move my character on my generated board?

Tags: python, python-3.x

A few days ago a started making my simple board game. First of all, I generate a board for the game. It looks like this:
[the gameboard generated for 13x13](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBGIR.png)

Secondly, I place my character on the board, which is 'A':
[The player placed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgLGv.png)

I made a dice for it which generates numbers from 1 to 6.

My goal right now is to get the 'A' character moving around by the dice on the '*' symbols, until it gets at the top left corner:
[I need to get here by the dice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3yMU.png)

So here is my code that I tried:

```
import math
import random

import os
board= []
def generator(boardsize):
    for row in range(boardsize+1):
            brow = []
            for column in range(boardsize+1):
                if row == column == 0:
                    brow.append(' ')
                elif row==0:
                    brow.append(str(column-1)[-1])
                elif column==0:
                    brow.append(str(row-1)[-1])
                elif ((math.ceil(boardsize/2)-1 )<= column) and(column <= (math.ceil(boardsize/2)+1)) or ((math.ceil(boardsize/2)-1 )<= row) and(row <= (math.ceil(boardsize/2)+1)):
                    if row == 1 or column == 1 or row == boardsize or column == boardsize: 
                        brow.append('*')

                    else:
                        if row == (math.ceil(boardsize/2)) and column == (math.ceil(boardsize/2)):
                            brow.append('X')
                        elif row == (math.ceil(boardsize/2)) or column == (math.ceil(boardsize/2)): 
                            brow.append('D')
                        else:
                            brow.append('*') 
                else:
                    brow.append(' ')
            board.append(brow)

    return board

def print_table(x):
    os.system('cls')
    for x in board:
        print(' '.join(x))
number_from_dice= []
def dice():
    min = 1
    max = 6
    x = random.randint(min, max)
    number_from_dice[:]= [x]
    return number_from_dice


def player1(x):
    generator(x)
    prev_char_y = 1
    prev_char_x = math.ceil(x/2)+1
    char_y= 1
    char_x= math.ceil(x/2)+1
    board[char_y][char_x] = "A"
    print_table(x)
    dice()
    f = number_from_dice[0]
    for i in range(f):
       if(char_y<x):
        if (board[char_y+1][char_x]) == '*':

            char_y= char_y +1
            board[char_y][char_x] = "A"
            board[prev_char_y][prev_char_x] = '*'
            prev_char_x = char_x
            prev_char_y = char_y
            print_table(x)
        else:
            if(char_x!=x):
                char_x2 = char_x
                if (board[char_y][char_x+1]=='*'):
                    char_x = char_x +1
                    board[char_y][char_x] = "A"
                    board[prev_char_y][prev_char_x] = '*'
                    prev_char_x = char_x
                    prev_char_y = char_y
                    print_table(x)
                else:
                    if (board[char_y+1][char_x]) == '*':
                                    char_y= char_y +1
                                    board[char_y][char_x] = "A"
                                    board[prev_char_y][prev_char_x] = '*'
                                    prev_char_x = char_x
                                    prev_char_y = char_y
                                    print_table(x)
            else:
                        if (board[char_y][char_x2-1]) == '*':
                                    char_x2 = char_x2 -1
                                    board[char_y][char_x2] = "A"
                                    board[prev_char_y][prev_char_x] = '*'
                                    prev_char_x = char_x2
                                    prev_char_y = char_y
                                    print_table(x)
                        else:
                            if (board[char_y+1][char_x2]) == '*':
                                    char_y = char_y +1
                                    board[char_y][char_x2] = "A"
                                    board[prev_char_y][prev_char_x] = '*'
                                    prev_char_x = char_x2
                                    prev_char_y = char_y
                                    print_table(x)












    print('Number from dice: ', end='')
    print(f)

player1(13)
```

Does the technic I used have potential? Or is it too complicated? How would you do it?

Comment: Please be sure to followup with additional questions or else select an answer if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Just in a generic sense you've made it overly complicated.

Consider this - the board, as far as movement is concerned, is just a set of ordered spaces.

But right now you have information about how the board is created as part of the player code.

Best to separate this, and you will find that things get simpler.

Instead, have the player simply track it's progress, in other words, what numbered space is it on.

Then you can generate the board and, knowing the space numbers, you can see if it matches the player location.

And then take it one step further (and simpler still) and just draw the board on a 2D array, and then output that, instead of trying to figure out the board as you go line-by-line.